# PyDub play audio from variable

Tags: python, pydub

I have a function that can generate WAV audio frames into a list. Is there any way I can play audio from that list without using an intermediate file to generate an `AudioSegment` object?

**EDIT:** For reference, [this](https://gitlab.com/Noammac/morse-practice/blob/master/morse_to_sound.py) is my code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) object. Since my library uses [`wave.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.open), I can just input an IO-like object to save to and read from. I'm not sure that this is the most pythonic answer, but that is what I used.

Comment: that's what IO objects are for,  so unleass pydub already provides a documented way to solve your problem this is probably the pythonic solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instantiating `AudioSegment()` objects directly like so:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound = AudioSegment(
    # raw audio data (bytes)
    data=b'…',

    # 2 byte (16 bit) samples
    sample_width=2,

    # 44.1 kHz frame rate
    frame_rate=44100,

    # stereo
    channels=2
)
```

addendum: I see you're generating sound in your linked code snippet. You may be interested in [pydub's audio generators](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/generators.py)

```
from pydub.generators import Sine
from pydub import AudioSegment

sine_generator = Sine(300)

# 0.1 sec silence
silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=100)
dot = sine_generator.to_audio_segment(duration=150)
dash = sine_generator.to_audio_segment(duration=300)

signal = [dot, dot, dot, dash, dash, dash, dot, dot, dot]

output = AudioSegment.empty()
for piece in signal:
    output += piece + silence
```

and one final note: iteratively extending an `AudioSegment` like this can get slow. You might want to do something like [this Mixer example](https://gist.github.com/jiaaro/b610728a642bbaa28b3f1e5d3b6f9cf7)

Comment: Thanks for the advice on instantiating the AudioSegment with data of its own, didn't know I can do that. On the matter of using PyDub generators in my library, I think I'd rather not. I want to make it as independent as possible and understand the math behind sound at the same time.